# How to Build Qt with bazel build system?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, bazel, bazel-rules

I want to make a mono repo consisting of a desktop app and an Android app for desktop I am using qt and C++ to do the task but how to build the qt app with Bazel

I have tried to build using [rules_foreign_cc](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.5.1/index.html) but it does;t work how to achieve this.

WORKSPACE

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

# Download and setup rules_foreign_cc for CMake
http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-main",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/main.zip"],
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

# Load dependencies for CMake
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()
```

CMakeLists.txt on root

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(HelloWorld VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

BUILD File of src dir

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

cmake(
    name = "my_qt_project",
    lib_source = "main.cpp",
)
```

CmakeLists.txt on src

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\6.5.1\\mingw_64\\lib\\cmake")

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(HelloWorld
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app (argc, argv);

 QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
 button.show();

 return app.exec();
}
```

Error

```
PS C:\Users\srilakshmikanthanp\OneDrive\Documents\Code\Cpp> bazel build //src:my_qt_project
INFO: Analyzed target //src:my_qt_project (43 packages loaded, 7591 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: C:/users/srilakshmikanthanp/onedrive/documents/code/cpp/src/BUILD:3:6: Foreign Cc - CMake: Building my_qt_project failed: (Exit 1): bash.exe failed: error executing command (from target //src:my_qt_project) C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe -c bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/my_qt_project_foreign_cc/wrapper_build_script.sh
rules_foreign_cc: Build failed!
rules_foreign_cc: Keeping temp build directory and dependencies directory for debug.
rules_foreign_cc: Please note that the directories inside a sandbox are still cleaned unless you specify --sandbox_debug Bazel command line flag.
rules_foreign_cc: Printing build logs:
_____ BEGIN BUILD LOGS _____

Bazel external C/C++ Rules. Building library my_qt_project

bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/my_qt_project_foreign_cc/build_script.sh: line 86: pwd: -W: invalid option
pwd: usage: pwd [-LP]
mkdir: cannot create directory ΓÇÿ/bazel-outΓÇÖ: Permission denied
_____ END BUILD LOGS _____
rules_foreign_cc: Build wrapper script location: bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/my_qt_project_foreign_cc/wrapper_build_script.sh
rules_foreign_cc: Build script location: bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/my_qt_project_foreign_cc/build_script.sh
rules_foreign_cc: Build log location: bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/src/my_qt_project_foreign_cc/CMake.log

Target //src:my_qt_project failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.                                                                              
INFO: Elapsed time: 9.680s, Critical Path: 4.39s                                                                                                    
INFO: 4 processes: 4 internal.                                                                                                                      
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
PS C:\Users\srilakshmikanthanp\OneDrive\Documents\Code\Cpp>
```

Comment: Why would you have _bash_ here: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe` ?

Comment: I don't know but I am running Windows 11, is it a problem with Bazel?

Comment: I've never used Bazel, it just strikes me as a bit funny place to put bash in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rules_qt6](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/rules_qt6).

Under [tests](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/rules_qt6/tree/main/tests) you can find some examples.